For some reason 'last' command is not working on my Kali
Generally, last command i used for accessing /var/log/wtmp file. But I can't use it from today. After I installed the other package to activate last it is asking for a wtmp.db file open_database_ro: Cannot open database (/var/lib/wtmpdb/wtmp.db): unable to open database file.
Despite not having added any additional repositories, for some reason I think that there are new packages that are newly added in the repo. I've recently added VSCode, but here is the thing: I had everything okay 1 week ago. This thing happened after the upgrade (apt upgrade). Now I can't use the last command as usual.
What's going on?

It looks like your rolling Kali has transitioned from the old wtmp file to the new wtmpdb database. Have you logged in since upgrading? Assuming all the dependencies have been added to PAM correctly that should create the new file for you

As an aside you shouldn't really be installing development tools like Visual Studio Code on Kali. That's not what it's designed for

I'm new to using Linux. I had the same problem as you when trying to read wtmp, but the issue was fixed when I upgraded and reboote command, then try last command and its work.
